# Insert JSON String in to PostgreSQL table column

Tags: python, json, postgresql

Trying to insert following JSON String as is without formatting

```
str={
    "Trial": {
        "@id": "xxxxx",
        "key1": "aaaaaaaa (BAL-8557) aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "key2": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa , aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "key3": "Yes",
        "key4": "No",
        "key5": {
        "key5": [{
                    "@type": "ABC",
                    "$": "ABC121 "
                },
                {
                    "@type": "ABC",
                    "$": "ABC12133 "
                }]
        },
        "Indications": {
            "Indication": {
                "@id": "1308",
                "$": "aaaaaa"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in to following PostgreSQL DB

```
CREATE TABLE records
(
  id text,
  record json
)
```

Code I am using to perform the insert operation

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO trial_records(id, record) VALUES (%s, %s)", ('1', json.dumps(json.loads(str))))
```

Error I am getting

```
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'
```

Is this the right syntax to store json string as part of the column

Comment: You should remove your `json.loads` call. So it will be `json.dumps(str)`.

Comment: Thanks that solved it

Comment: @sashaaero put it as your answer.. So this question will not show in unanswered..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.loads(obj)` creates json object from string data.

`json.dumps(obj)` creates string from json object.

So you should change `json.dumps(json.loads(str))` to `json.dumps(str)`.

P.S.: I'd also don't recommend to call your variables as type names like `str`, `int`. You are making `str()` and `int()` call unable from current scope.